# Chemistry formula comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string of a chemical formula like this `"N4++e=>N2+N2"` into this `"N4+ + e => N2 + N2"`. But I am stuck dealing with the "++"

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
temp = "N4++e=>N2+N2"

lhs = temp.split("=>")[0]
rhs = temp.split("=>")[1]

# only showing code for the left hand side

temp = lhs.split("+")

temp1 = []
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if temp[i]=='':
        temp1[i-1] = temp[i-1] + "+"
    else:
        temp1.append(temp[i]) 

lhs = temp1
```

After this code I get something like lhs = ['N4+', 'e'] and I can put it together how I want.

But is there a better and faster alternative? I can have quite long lists of chemical reactions.

Comment: You clearly aren't actually running this code, you rascal.  `slpit`?

Comment: Good point! Should have copied the code. There is a bit more before I am doing the chemistry thing.

Comment: Do you need the output `N4+ + e => N2 + N2` or `N4 + + e => N2 + N2` or `N4 + e => N2 + N2`?

Comment: Are you just asking for a faster way to produce the same list that this code generates, or a better way to approach the overall problem?  If you want a better overall approach you might need to explain the problem in more precise terms; chemistry class was more than two decades ago for me.

Comment: I want to split N4++e into N4+ + e. To get the white spaces between the N4+ and the next + are my problem. I am looking for a faster and more elegant solution.

Comment: `temp = temp.replace("++", "+ + ")`?

Comment: That works if I only have two species. But occasionally I have three. Like: N2++N2+N2. Then I'm stuck with N2+ + N2+N2. Maybe I should test if the next character is a number or a letter?

Comment: It's just different conventions how to write it down. Comsol is fine with N2++N2+N2, but another software wants N2+ + N2 + N2. N2+ is a nitrogen ion and N2 is nitrogen. The other software would interpret N2+N2 as one species when it really is two N2.

Comment: @arsho I am interested to get N4+ + e => N2 + N2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest doing this through multiple `replace` operations, e.g.:

```
temp = "N4++e=>N2+N2"
print(temp.replace("+", " + ").replace(" +  +", "+ +").replace("=>", " => "))
# N4+ + e => N2 + N2
```

This is making a lot of assumptions about the types of inputs you might get and the result you want to achieve, though.  For a more robust solution you might want to look at writing a lexer (e.g. with [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn3)).

Comment: This is really helpful! replace makes it faster and I will look into PLY.